# Getting errors from NDSolve; what solver should I use instead?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

How can I remove the error in the code below? I don't know the reason for getting this error.

```
r0 = L;
Nu = 50;
l = 4;
phi = Pi L^2/(l r0 Nu Sin[t]);
X1 = r0 Sin[phi/2];
X0 = -r0 Sin[phi/2];
Y0 = r0 Cos[phi/2];
Y1 = Y0;
X = (Tan[phi/2 + t] X1 + Tan[phi/2] X0 + Y1 - Y0) (Tan[phi/2 + t] + Tan[phi/2])^(-1);
NDSolve[X0 + l Cos[phi/2 - t]/2 - X == 0, t[L], {L, 30, 70}]
```

> NDSolve::dvnoarg: The function t appears with no arguments.

#### Edit

After the helpful comment:

```
r0 = L;
Nu = 50;
l = 4;
phi = Pi L^2/(l r0 Nu Sin[t[L]]);
X1 = r0 Sin[phi/2];
X0 = -r0 Sin[phi/2];
Y0 = r0 Cos[phi/2];
Y1 = Y0;
X = 
  (Tan[phi/2 + t[L]] X1 + Tan[phi/2] X0 + Y1 - Y0) 
    (Tan[phi/2 + t[L]] + Tan[phi/2])^(-1);
NDSolve[X0 + l Cos[phi/2 - t[L]]/2 - X == 0, t[L], {L, 30, 70}]
```

But now, the error is:

> NDSolve::derivs: No derivatives of dependent variables were found in the equations. NDSolve is designed to solve differential or differential algebraic equations. Use NSolve or FindRoot to numerically solve algebraic equations.

I want to find solutions of $t$ as a function of $L$. But I don't know what Mathematica function to use.

Comment: Replace both instances of  `Tan[phi/2 + t] ` with `Tan[phi/2 + t[L]] ` and `Cos[phi/2 - t]` with `Cos[phi/2 - t[L]]` and `Sin[t]` with `Sin[t[L]]`. However, you will still have errors.

Comment: What is it that you _really_ want to do? `NDSolve` is for solving differential equations, but yours is an algebraic one. Maybe you could describe with words and math what's the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I don't see what is unclear about "I want to find solutions of $t$ as a function of $L$."  (I can see that this was added after the initial post, but it was also added ten hours before being closed.)

Comment: To @corey979. Like Michael E2, I don't see, that this question should be unclear. The answer of Michael E2 and my alternative answer as comment show, it is solveable. Please release the hold.

Comment: To @Daniel Lichtblau. Like Michael E2, I don't see, that this question should be unclear. The answer of Michael E2 and my alternative answer as comment show, it is solveable. Please release the hold.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are 22 different solutions, because there are lots of solutions for `t[30]` at `L = 30` modulo `2 Pi` (there may be more near `±Pi`, which the discretization missed, though; decrease `MaxStepSize` in the code for `rts` and you'll see):

```
eqn = X0 + l Cos[phi/2 - t[L]]/2 - X == 0;

Block[{L = 30},
  rts = Sort@
    Flatten@Last@Reap@NDSolve[{t'[s] == 1, t[1/100] == 1/100,
         WhenEvent[
          eqn && Abs[eqn /. Equal -> Subtract] < 10^16 /. 
            t[L] -> t[s] // Evaluate, Sow[t[s]]]},
        {}, {s, -Pi + 2^-25, Pi - 2^-25}, MaxStepSize -> 0.01, 
        WorkingPrecision -> 3 $MachinePrecision]
  ];

sol[n_Integer] /; 1 <= n <= Length@rts := (* pretty good solution *)
  NDSolve[{Equal @@@ First@Solve[D[eqn, L], t'[L]], t[30] == rts[[n]]},
   t, {L, 30, 70}];

sol[n_Integer] /; 1 <= n <= Length@rts := (* a more accurate solution *)
  NDSolve[{Equal @@@ First@Solve[D[eqn, L], t'[L]], t[30] == rts[[n]]},
   t, {L, 30, 70}, 
   Method -> {"Projection", "Invariants" -> {eqn /. Equal -> Subtract}}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All];

Plot[t[L] /. Join @@ Table[sol[n], {n, 1, Length@rts}] // 
  Evaluate, {L, 30, 70}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Yep, lots of potential initial conditions (infinitely many, I believe):

```
Block[{L = 30, neqn},
   neqn = 
    Cos[1/400 L \[Pi] Csc[t[L]] + t[L]] Cos[
          1/400 L \[Pi] Csc[t[L]]] (eqn /. Equal -> Subtract) /. 
        t[L] -> t // Expand // Together // Numerator;
   rts = t /. Join[
      NSolve[{neqn, 1/1000 < t < Pi - 1/1000}, t, 
       WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision],
      NSolve[{neqn, -Pi + 1/1000 < t < -1/1000}, t, 
       WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]
      ]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.76056, Null}  *)

Length@rts
(*  898  *)
```

Comment: Appendix to the fine answer of @Michael E2. The same with less code: `equ[L_] = X0 + l Cos[phi/2 - t[L]]/2 - X // Simplify;`  Solve for starting values. Exclude areas with infinit many solutions. `sol1 = t[30] /. 
   Solve[equ[30] == 
      0 && (1/100 < t[30] < 310/100 || -310/100 < t[30] < -1/100), 
    t[30]];` Differentate equation. `dequ[L] = D[equ[L], L] // Simplify; ` NDSolve with found starting values.  `ndsol = NDSolve[{dequ[L] == 0, t[30] == #}, t, {L, 30, 70}] & /@ sol1; ` Plot gives the same result  `Plot[Evaluate[t[L] /. ndsol], {L, 30, 70}, PlotRange -> All] `